# How to scale random simulations with parallelism in Swift?

Tags: swift, random, parallel-processing

I'm playing around in Swift 5.1 (on the Mac) running little simulations of tennis matches. Naturally part of the simulation is randomly choosing who wins each point.

Below is the relevant part of the code where I do the parallelism.

```
func combine(result: MatchTally)
{
    overallTally.add(result: result)
}

DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: cycleCount){iterationNumber in
    var counter = MatchTally()
    for _ in 1...numberOfSimulations
    {
        let result = playMatch(between: playerOne, and: playerTwo)
        counter[result.0, result.1] += 1
    }
    combiningQueue.sync {combine(result: counter)}
}
```

With an appropriate simulation run count chosen, a single queue takes about 5s. If I set the concurrent queues to 2, the simulation now takes 3.8s per queue (i.e. it took 7.2s). Doubling again to 4 queues results in 4.8s / queue. And finally with 6 queues (the machine is a 6 core Intel i7) things take 5.6s / queue.

For those who need more convincing that this relates to random number generating (I'm using `Double.random(0...1)`) I replaced the code where most of the random outcomes are generated with a fixed result (I couldn't replace the second place as I still needed a tie-break) and adjusted the number of simulations appropriately, the outcomes were as follows:

- 1 queue: 5s / queue
- 2 queues: 2.7s / queue
- 4 queues: 1.9s / queue
- 6 queues: 1.7s / queue

So as you can see, it appears that the randomness part is resistant to running in parallel.

I've also tried with drand48() and encountered the same issues. Anybody know whether this is just the way things are?

Xcode 11.3,
Swift 5.1,
macOS 10.15.3,
Mac mini 2018,
6 core i7 (but have encountered the same thing over the years on different hardware)

For anyone interested in reproducing this themselves, here is some code I created and Alexander added to.

```
import Foundation

func formatTime(_ date: Date) -> String
{
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = "h:mm:ss.SSS"
    return df.string(from: date)
}

func something(_ iteration: Int)
{
    var tally = 0.0
    let startTime = Date()
    print("Start #\(iteration) - \(formatTime(startTime))")

    for _ in 1...1_000_000
    {
        tally += Double.random(in: 0...100)
//      tally += 3.5
    }
    let endTime = Date()
    print("End   #\(iteration) - \(formatTime(endTime)) - elapsed: \(endTime.timeIntervalSince(startTime))")
}

print("Single task performed on main thread")
something(0)    //  Used to get a baseline for single run

print("\nMultiple tasks performed concurrently")
DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 5, execute: something)
```

Swapping out the random additive in the loop for a fixed one demonstrates how well the code scales in one scenario, but not the other.

Comment: " 3.8s per queue (i.e. it took 7.2s)." That's not really how parallelism works. For all you know, both tasks took 7.2 seconds. Profile deeper into the start/end times, and see where the threads are spending their time

Comment: Perhaps my description wasn't clear. To do one unit of work took 5 seconds. To do two units took 7.2s. Both tasks did take that amount of time (I do measure task completion time) and that's the problem. A task shouldn't slow down when another one is running in parallel, if there aren't shared resources.

Comment: Yes, I understand the issue, I'm just looking into the details of the measurements you provided. "Both tasks did take that amount of time" So both tasks individually took 7.2s of CPU time, and when running concurrently, took 7.2s of "wall clock time"? Hmmm... Could you try cooking up a minimal verifiable example that reproduces this problem?

Comment: Not forgetting that the situation was dramatically improved in terms of scalability by changing one line of code, taking out the random function and replacing it with a fixed result. Therefore one would imagine this is where the problem is happening. I wish I were competent enough to look at profiler results for thread switching etc and garner more information, but I'm not at that level.

Comment: Does the problem reproduce if you change the workload? E.g. use a simple busy loop to suck up CPU time, without needing to call your real workload?

Comment: I'll try to rephrase as I may be misunderstanding what you are saying. Running a single task took 5s. Running 2 tasks concurrently took 7.2s (which is an improvement). But running 6 tasks concurrently took 34s (all tasks finishing roughly the same time).

IF things were **perfectly** scalable, 6 concurrent tasks should take the same amount of time as 1 task. However I am seeing negative gains in total work rate. But only when I involve random generators.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207615/discussion-between-alexander-reinstate-monica-and-ray).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the solution is to use a less 'fashionable' generator such as `drand48()`. I believed I had already testing that option, but seems that I was wrong. It seems this doesn't suffer from the same issue so I guess it is inherent to `arc4random()` which I believe `Double.random()` is based upon.

The other positive is that it is about 4 times faster to return a value. So my simulations won't be cryptographically secure, but then what tennis match is?